# Plastic number rectangle

Tags: graphics, recursion

I'd like to find a nice recursive way of making this image

[image]

based on the [plastic constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number)

Here's a start

```
Module[{},
 ψ = ((9 + Sqrt[69])/18)^(1/3) + ((9 - Sqrt[69])/18)^(1/3);
 poly = {{0, 0}, {1 + ψ, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}, {0, 1 + 1/ψ}};
 pt = {(1 + ψ)^2/(1 + 2*ψ), (1 + ψ)/(1 + 2*ψ)};
 recs = {{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1 + 1/ψ}, {0, 1 + 1/ψ}},
         {{1 + 1/ψ, 1}, {1 + ψ, 1}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}, {1 + 1/ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}},
         {{1 + 1/ψ, 0}, {1 + ψ, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1/(1 + ψ)}, {1 + 1/ψ, 1/(1 + ψ)}},
         {{1, 0}, {ψ, 0}, {ψ, 1/(1 + ψ)}, {1, 1/(1 + ψ)}}};
 Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[Black], Black, Polygon@poly,
    White, Polygon /@ recs,
    PointSize[.02], Red, Point[pt],
    Line[{poly[[4]], poly[[2]]}],
    Line[{{1, 0}, poly[[3]]}]
   }]]
```

[image]

[Here is more complete code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinq321/plastic/main/lengthy). It does the job, but it's very clunky, and barely makes use of any recursion - not at all how I'd like to achieve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Determine plastic constant:

```
plastic = NSolveValues[x^3 == x + 1, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // First
```

`1.32471795724474602596090885448`

Set initial square:

```
initVertices = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
```

Define one step. I'm taking one step to be a 90 degree rotation, a scaling process, and a translation.

```
plasticSpiralStep[vertices_] :=
  With[
    {rotationPoint = vertices[[2]],
     scale = 1/plastic,
     translationVector = vertices[[3]] - vertices[[2]]},
    TranslationTransform[translationVector]@*
    ScalingTransform[{1, 1}/plastic, rotationPoint]@*
    RotationTransform[-Pi/2, rotationPoint]@vertices]
```

Test it out:

```
Graphics[Polygon[NestList[plasticSpiralStep, initVertices, 8]]]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice - that was what I was after - thank you

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

For each step, you need an initial vertex and initial direction. After each step, the direction is rotated by $\pi/2$ and rescaled by $1/\rho$, and the new initial vertex is chosen as next-to-the-previous-one.

```
ρ = First@NSolveValues[x^3 == x + 1, x, Reals];

rot = RotationMatrix[-Pi/2];
makeSquare[{pt_, dir_}] := Module[{pts},
  pts = {pt, pt + dir, pt + dir + rot . dir, pt + rot . dir};
  Sow[Polygon[pts]];  
  {pt + rot . dir, rot . dir/ρ}
]

Graphics@Last@Reap@Nest[makeSquare, {{0, 0}, {-1, 0}}, 25]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Domen. A question: Where or how have you learned Mathematica?

Comment: Uhmm ... Coding by myself, documentation, StackExchange and watching Live CEOing :)

Comment: Your knowledge is quite impressive. I'm reading all of your answers!

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

- `f[{x,y}]` to find the intersection point  along the vertical direction.
- `g[{x,y}]` to find the intersection point along the horizontal direction.

```
Clear[f,g];
f[{x_, y_}] := 
  SolveValues[{{u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{x, y}, {0, 1}], {u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{{0, 1 + 1/ψ}, {1 + ψ, 0}}]}, {u, v}, 
    Reals] // First;
g[{x_, y_}] := 
  SolveValues[{{u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{x, y}, {1, 0}], {u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}}]}, {u, v}, 
    Reals] // First;
ψ = SolveValues[x^3 == x + 1, x, Reals] // First;
pts = ComposeList[Table[If[OddQ@i, g, f], {i, 12}], {0, 0}];
rectan[p1_, p2_] = 
  Rectangle[p1, p2 + RotationMatrix[π/2] . (p2 - p1)];
Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{1, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}}], 
  Line[{{0, 1 + 1/ψ}, {1 + ψ, 0}}], {FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[Black], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}]}, {Black, 
   rectan @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]}, {Arrowheads[.03], Thick, Orange, 
   Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]}}]
```

[image]

**Original**

A start point,need to be updated.

```
Clear[f, g];
f[{x_, y_}] := 
  SolveValues[{{u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{x, y}, {0, 1}], {u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{{0, 1 + 1/ψ}, {1 + ψ, 0}}]}, {u, v}, 
    Reals] // First;
g[{x_, y_}] := 
  SolveValues[{{u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{x, y}, {1, 0}], {u, v} ∈ 
      InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}}]}, {u, v}, 
    Reals] // First;
ψ = SolveValues[x^3 == x + 1, x, Reals] // First;
pts = ComposeList[{f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g, f, g}, {1, 0}];
Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}]}, Red, Line[pts], 
  Blue, Line[{{1, 0}, {1 + ψ, 1 + 1/ψ}}], 
  Line[{{0, 1 + 1/ψ}, {1 + ψ, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

So far the shortest code and also rotation-less (or any other "graphic transformation"-less).

```
fu = {Identity, Reverse};
n = 1;
fi = Root[-1 - x + x^3, 1];
NestList[{{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 2]]}, {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}} &@
    fu[[Mod[n++, 2, 1]]][{#[[2]], #[[2]] + (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/
        fi}] &, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 20];
Graphics[Rectangle @@@ %]
```

If `RootReduce` is used in `NestList`

```
NestList[RootReduce[{{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 2]]}, {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 
         2]]}} &@fu[[Mod[n++, 2, 
        1]]][{#[[2]], #[[2]] + (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/fi}]] &, {{0, 0}, {1,
    1}}, 10]
```

we get exact position of vertices of each square in simplest form:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Even shorter code:

```
fi = Root[-1 - x + x^3, 1];
NestList[# . {{0, -(1/fi), 0}, {1/fi, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}} &, {{0, 0, 
    1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 10];
Graphics3D[Cuboid @@@ %]
Graphics[(Rectangle @@ Most /@ #) & /@ %%]
```

[image]

[image]